# Properties of Groups Seen in Cayley Tables

Tags: group-theory, cayley-table

The following is a simple exercise from "Guide to Abstract Algebra 1st Ed Carol Whitehead".

---

**Problem 6.2b.1**

The following is part of a Cayley table for a group $G = {a,b,c,d}$, with respect to operation $\circ$.

$$
\begin{array}{l|*{4}{lr}}
    \circ    & a   & b   & c & d \\
    \hline
    a   & c   & \cdot   & \cdot & \cdot   \\
    b   & \cdot   & \cdot   & \cdot & a   \\
    c & \cdot   & \cdot   & \cdot & d   \\
    d & \cdot   & \cdot   & \cdot & \cdot   \\
\end{array} 
$$

(a) Which is the identity element of $(G,\circ)$?

(b) Show that there is only one way to fill the rest o the table, justifying each step.
Note: You are not required to verify that $\circ$ is associative.

---

**My Solution Attempt:**

(a) We can see $c \circ d =d$, so the identity element is $c$.

(b) Since $c$ is the identity, we can fill in the $c$ rows and columns.

$$
\begin{array}{l|*{4}{lr}}
    \circ    & a   & b   & c & d \\
    \hline
    a   & c   & \cdot   & a & \cdot   \\
    b   & \cdot   & \cdot   & b & a   \\
    c & a   & b   & c & d   \\
    d & \cdot   & \cdot   & d & \cdot   \\
\end{array} 
$$

I know also from an earlier theorem in the book that each element of a group appears only once in each row or column.

Looking at $a \circ b$, this could be $b$ or $d$ if we note that $c$ and $a$ are already in that row. But $b$ is already in that column so $a \circ b$ must only be $d$.

Following this logic gives us the following:

$$
\begin{array}{l|*{4}{lr}}
    \circ    & a   & b   & c & d \\
    \hline
    a   & c   & d   & a & b   \\
    b   & d   & c  & b & a   \\
    c & a   & b   & c & d   \\
    d & b   & a   & d & c   \\
\end{array} 
$$

**My Question:** Is this correct?

I notice that in Cayley tables for groups, the rows and columns always follow a single order, or its reverse. That is $a,b,c,d$ or $d, c, b, a$ but never something like $a, d, c, b$. **Additional Question:** What is the reason for this?

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely correct. Please clarify the addition question. What do you mean when you say "the rows and columns always follow a single order, or its reverse" ?

Comment: hi @Category_Theorist - the rows and columns are always $a,b,c,d$ or $d,c,b,a$ shift-cycled eg $b,c,d,a$. We never see $a,b,d,c$, for example. Another way to say this is that vertically or horizontally $b$ or $d$ are next to $c$ but never $a$.

Comment: For your additional question, you are incorrect in your assumption. Please look at more Cayley tables to see why.

Comment: For a small example of what Somos mentions, you might consider the Cayley table of the (unique) group with elements $a, b, c, d$ with identity $a$ and with the property that $b + b = c + c = a$.

Comment: "What is the reason for this" Actually there is another answer: all the groups you've looked at must be cyclic groups.

Comment: thanks @JBL I am self-teaching so will look up cyclic groups. very helpful comment.

Comment: You're welcome!